# Prove any normal complex square matrix can be expressed as product of some matrix and its adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a complex, normal (i.e. $AA^*=A^*A$) matrix such that all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive real numbers.

Prove that there exists an invertible matrix $H$ such that $A=H^*H$.

I looked at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232624/prove-normal-matrix-is-4th-power-of-some-self-adjoint-matrix) and tried using the principle axis theorem (i.e. $A=(UBU^*)^2$ for some unitary matrix $U$ and diagonal matrix $B$, but I can't proceed further from there.

I noticed that $(H^*H)^* = H^*(H^*)^* = H^*H$, so $A$ must be Hermitian.  I think (but am not sure) that if all eigenvalues of $A$ are real then $A$ must be Hermitian, but even if I can prove this, I still need to show that any Hermitian matrix can be expressed as $H^*H$ for some invertible $H$.

How can I go about proving this?

Comment: Normal in general does not imply hermitian. Are your eigenvslues strictly positive? Then you can use the spectral theorm to make the conclusion (if the diagonal matrix represantion of $A $ has a square root then $\dots$.

Comment: I solved it.  I'm not too sure how the spectral theorem comes into play but I did the following:

$A$ is normal $\implies$ $A = UDU^*$ (principle axis theorem, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix).

$D$ is the list of eigenvalues, so it must be real and positive (from question premise), so we can let $D = BB$ (where $B$ is a diagonal, real positive matrix, thus is Hermitian)

$\therefore A = UDU^* = UBBU^* = (UB)(UB)^* = (UB)^*(UB)$

Comment: The spectral theorem justifies the existance of matrices $U,D $ which I'd guess you may know under a different name.

Comment: @AnyAD My understanding of principle axis theorem is that: $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is normal $\implies$ there exists unitary $U$ such that $U^*AU \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is diagonal. My understanding of spectral theorem is that: $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is Hermitian $\implies$ there exists unitary $U$ such that $U^*AU \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is **real** and diagonal.  Hermitian is a stricter condition than normal, so it makes sense to give a stricter result that the diagonal matrix must be real. I've learnt these two theorems from different places, so I might be confused. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, then I can't prove that $A$ is Hermitian, so I would not be able to use spectral theorem at all.